# How to define LINQ expression from generic Func delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates, expression-trees

Say I have a method with an input parameter named `collectionSelector` of type `Func<TEntity, ICollection<TCollection>>`.

I'd like to use this input parameter to load EF entities by using this method on an instance of `DbContext`:

```
context.Entry(entity).Collection(collectionExpression).Load()
```

The [Collection method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671324%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) accepts a parameter of type `Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>>`

I've searched around, but can't figure out how to initialize an Expression instance from an Func instance. Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you define your method to take an expression:

```
void Process(Expression<Func<TEntity,ICollection<TCollection>>> collectionSelector)
{
  context.Entry(entity).Collection(collectionExpression).Load()
}
```

Now you can call it passing in a lambda:

```
Process(x=>x.GenerateCollection());
```

And the C# compiler will take care of converting the lambda to an expression for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I've searched around, but can't figure out how to initialize an Expression instance from an Func instance.

You can't. A `Func` is a delegate that points to a compiled method, there's no way to get an expression tree from that (well, maybe it's possible, but certainly not easily since you would need to decompile the method).

Depending on the context, a lambda expression can be compiled either to an anonymous method or to an expression tree. There is no conversion between the method and the expression...

Comment: The other way around possible? Obtain an generic Func from an Expression that contains the Func?

Comment: The Expression doesn't *contain* the Func, it just represents its syntax tree... But you can compile an Expression into a Func, using the Compile method